# What could be causing the newly changed password not allowing to login?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac, asp.net-identity-2, katana

I am using Web API 2 with Identity 2. I have everything hooked up using Autofac. When a user changes his password, the newly changed password doesn't work unless I restart the api.

Seems like an Katana and Autofac issue but I am not sure where to look.

Global.asax.cs

```cs
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ContainerConfig.Configure);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ...
    }
}
```

ContainerConfig.cs

```cs
public class ContainerConfig
{
    public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        const string publicClientId = "self";

        // ContainerConfig Config
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var elasticsearchUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchUrl"];
        var elasticSearchIndex = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchIndex"];

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new BimDataContext(connectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>().AsSelf();
        builder.Register(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(c.Resolve<BimDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.Register(c => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(c.Resolve<BimDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).As<IAuthenticationManager>();
        builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
        {
            DataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Oporo.io Identity​")
        });

        builder.RegisterType<SimpleRefreshTokenProvider>().As<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>();

        builder.Register(c => new ApplicationOAuthProvider(
            publicClientId, 
            c.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>(), 
            c.Resolve<IAuthRepository>()))
            .As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // UoW registration: being explicit
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Repositories registration
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ClientRepository).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerDependency();

        // Services registration
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ClientService).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterType<EntityPersistedEventHandler>().As<IEntityPersistedEventHandler>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<COBieIndexingService>().As<ICOBieIndexingService>();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ClientSearchService).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("SearchService"))
            .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
            {
                new NamedParameter("connectionstring", elasticsearchUrl),
                new NamedParameter("defaultIndex", elasticSearchIndex),
            })
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterType<IfcFileImportTask>().As<IIfcFileImportTask>();
        builder.RegisterType<COBieFileImportTask>().As<ICOBieFileImportTask>();

        // Hangfire registration
        builder.RegisterType<BackgroundJobClient>().As<IBackgroundJobClient>();

        // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        JobActivator.Current = new AutofacJobActivator(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

ApplicationUserManager.cs

```cs
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store,
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options)
        : base(store)
    {
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            this.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        PublicClientId = "self";

        //var provider = (IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider) GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider));
        var provider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();

        //var tokenProvider = (IAuthenticationTokenProvider) GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationTokenProvider));
        var tokenProvider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>();

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = provider,
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            RefreshTokenProvider = tokenProvider,
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just post tons of code here and say "tell me what the problem is". If you're interested in anyone helping you, please reduce your code to the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sure, the amount of code it to give people the context, if I knew exactly where the problem is, I would have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with getting the same instance of user manager in ApplicationOAuthProvider

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var container = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var userManager = scope.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>();
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

           AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            properties.Dictionary.Add("as:client_id", context.ClientId ?? string.Empty);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }
```